# Delete strings from an html file containing a pattern using unix commands

Tags: unix, shell, sed, awk

I have a messy html that looks like this:

```
<div id=":0.page.0" class="page-element" style="width: 1620px;">
 <div>
  <img src="viewer_files/viewer_004.png" class="page-image" style="width: 800px; height: 1131px; display: none;">
  <img src="viewer_files/viewer_005.png" class="page-image" style="width: 1600px;">
 </div>
</div>// this repeats 100+ times with different 'src' attributes
```

**Now this is all one line actually** (i have formatted in multiple lines for easy readibility). I am trying to remove all `<img>` tags that have `display:none;` set in the inline css. Is it possible to use sed/awk or some other unix command to achieve this? I think if it were a well indented html document, it would've been easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e "s/<img[^>]*display: none;[^>]*>//g" filein
```

A quick explanation about sed :

s stands for substitution
/ are delimiters

s means that the first field will be a pattern to be search, that will be replaced by the second one. The last one are options.
g means global (replace it many times if many matches are found).

to replace inplace : sed -i -e "..."

Comment: should be `display: *none\b` instead of `display: none;`

Comment: @Pumbaa80 what is the difference?

Comment: Matches zero or more spaces, instead of exactly one.

Comment: also, it matches `"display: none"` and `"display: none ;"`

Answer (score 3):

HTML and regexes are a notoriously bad match, so you probably want something that is HTML-aware. I'd probably go for something like [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), but there are no doubt other options that are more shell-friendly, or suitable for any favourite scripting language you may have.

Answer (score 3):

I would use either [Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.35/Twig.pm) or [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to do this kind of processing. A lot more reliable than sed/awk/grep. Since your pattern is regular and repeating, they would work too.

Comment: +1 love xmlstarlet as much as I can love anything related to XML.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/<img.*display: none;[^>]>//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

That would do it

```
sed -e "s@<img.*display: none;.*>@@g" FILINAME
```

Comment: Isn't the second .* going to match greedily?

Comment: it removed all the img tags :|

Comment: Well, it did work on original sample. But if greedy would be a problem we can always replace . with [^>]

Comment: Are u sure? I just tried it with your file. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Sed has several commands, but most people only learn the substitute command: "s".
A useful command deletes every line that matches the restriction: "**d**".

```
sed -e "/<img[^>]*display: none;[^>]*>/d" File
```

Be carreful it's delete entire line.